What would be the right Base model and prompt for Aws Bedrock to translate Json files?
we'd like to leverage on AWS bedrock to translate from one language to another json files
preserving json schema and translating only the values (not the keys)
What I was able to achieve so far is the following

import {
  BedrockRuntimeClient,
  InvokeModelCommand,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-bedrock-runtime";

const client = new BedrockRuntimeClient({
  region: "us-west-2",
  // credentials:{
  //    secretAccessKey:process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  //    accessKeyId:process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID
  // }
});

const JsonInput = { hello: "world" };
const langFrom = "english";
const langTo = "italian";

let prompt = `
Given this JSON Object stringified : ${JSON.stringify(JsonInput)}
Please keep intact json keys and translate only json values from ${langFrom} to ${langTo}.
Providing the result : ensure to maintain the exact same JSON Object structure without changes but the translation. 
Do not add any additional strings, don't escape characters. Provide an output having the same structure as the input.
`;

// console.log("-----------------------------");
// console.log(prompt);
// console.log("-----------------------------");

const input = {
  modelId: "amazon.titan-text-lite-v1",
  contentType: "application/json",
  accept: "application/json",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    inputText: prompt,
    textGenerationConfig: {
      maxTokenCount: 512,
    },
  }),
};

(async () => {
  const command = new InvokeModelCommand(input);
  const resp = await client.send(command);

  const decodedResponseBody = JSON.parse(new TextDecoder().decode(resp.body));
  console.log(decodedResponseBody.results[0].outputText);
})();


But the results are not precise/consistent
And also the "amazon.titan-text-lite-v1" model seems not to be "trained enough"  to handle json
If I post the same prompt on chatGpt playground it seems to work as expected.
So I wonder if I'm using the wrong base model "amazon.titan-text-lite-v1"
what could be the best fit?
Or If I should workout more on the prompt to make it work consistently and provide the json response I'm looking for...
